# How to create a Custom Action to randomly redirect to a page in FlutterFlow.io?

Tags: flutterflow

I would like to create an action to randomly redirect to a page. I have tried with this custom code but it doesn't work....

I have created routes on the pages so that the string matches the names <String> pages = ['page01', 'page02', 'page03', 'page04'];

I would like to create a custom action so that when clicking on a button, it randomly redirects to any of the pages

Could you help me fix it please? It would help me a lot to move forward with the project. Thank you very much in advance!

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

// Set your action name, define your arguments and return parameter,
// and then add the boilerplate code using the green button on the right!

import 'dart:math';

Future<void> randomPageRedirect(BuildContext context) async {
  List<String> pages = ['page01', 'page02', 'page03', 'page04'];
  Random random = new Random();
  int randomNumber = random.nextInt(pages.length);
  String randomPage = pages[randomNumber];
  await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/$randomPage');
}
```